# Akka Kubernetes API is not able to access Service account token

Tags: kubernetes, akka, amazon-eks

We are working with Akka Kubernetes API to connect to other pods in the Kubernetes cluster(AWS EKS) to form a cluster. But we are getting the following error when the token is being read

```
[ERROR] 2022-12-01 12:05:53.635+0000 [cloud-poi-ha-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] a.d.k.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Error reading api-token from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

When we checked the token that's gets mounted on the pod, we observed it's not the token from the service account we intend to use but the default token. This causes the discovery of other pods fail with error 403.

```
[INFO ] 2022-12-01 12:07:19.999+0000 [cloud-poi-ha-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] a.d.k.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Querying for pods with label selector: [app=cloud-poi]. Namespace: [fdnbug-cloud-poi-ha-bugfix-def-85666]. Port: [None]
[WARN ] 2022-12-01 12:07:20.011+0000 [cloud-poi-ha-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] a.d.k.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery - Forbidden to communicate with Kubernetes API server; check RBAC settings. Response: [{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"fdnbug-cloud-poi-ha-bugfix-def-85666\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
]
[WARN ] 2022-12-01 12:07:20.013+0000 [cloud-poi-ha-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] a.m.c.b.i.BootstrapCoordinator - Resolve attempt failed! Cause: akka.discovery.kubernetes.KubernetesApiServiceDiscovery$KubernetesApiException: Forbidden when communicating with the Kubernetes API. Check RBAC settings.
```

Our Statefulset and ServiceAccount manifests looks like:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-ne-ha
  namespace: somenamespace
  labels:
    componentName: ne
    app: some-app
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ne-r-cluster-managers
  namespace: somenamespace
  labels:
    componentName: ne
    app: some-app
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
      - pods/status
      - pods/log
      - statefulsets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ne-rb-cluster-managers
  namespace: somenamespace
  labels:
    componentName: ne
    app: someapp
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: ne-r-cluster-managers
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sa-ne-ha
    namespace: somenamespace
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: ne-ha
  namespace: somenamespace
  labels:
    componentName: ne-ha
    app: someapp
    version: someversion
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
    prometheus.io/port: "9252"
spec:
  serviceName: ne-headless
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      componentName: ne-ha
      app: someapp
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        componentName: ne-ha
        app: someapp
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: sa-ne-ha
      containers:
        - name: ne-ha
          image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: ${CONTAINERS_RESOURCES_CPU_REQUESTS}
              memory: ${CONTAINERS_RESOURCES_MEMORY_REQUESTS}
            limits:
              cpu: ${CONTAINERS_RESOURCES_CPU_LIMITS}
              memory: ${CONTAINERS_RESOURCES_MEMORY_LIMITS}
          command:
            - "/microservice/bin"
          env:
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /ready
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 30
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 30
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /alive
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 130
            periodSeconds: 30
            failureThreshold: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 5
---
```

Have someone encountered a similar issue and was able to resolve it?

Comment: share yaml definition of hope SA and other permission are proper to list the POD and deployment point correct SA.

Comment: added yaml files.